# Как вывести несколько последних элементов из строки

Tags: java

Например из  строки "aaaaaasd" вывести только "sd"

Comment: String.substring() вас чем-то не устраивает?

Comment: Если мой ответ вам подошел, отметьте его верным, нажав на галочку.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String str = "aaaaaasd";
String new_str = str.substring(a,b);
```

Где a - индекс начала, b - индекс конца. Если нужно вырезать с какого то знака до конца, то указывать только a.
В вашем случае нужно так

```
String new_str = str.substring(str.length()-2);
System.out.println(new_str);
```

Тоесть вырезаем два последних знака и выводим их

Comment: Здесь неплохо бы проверить, что в строке есть хотя бы 2 символа, а то можно получить exception.